# How to skip over rows causing `Integrity Error` in unique constraints?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

This is a model that I have and I want to modify it so One Advisor can only have one response with status Accepted, to do that I am creating a unique constrain in class Meta:

```
class AdvisorResponse(UUIDTimeStampedModel):
    chat_request = models.ForeignKey(ChatRequest, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                     related_name='advisor_responses', null=True)
    advisor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,
                                blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ADVISOR_REQUEST_STATUS,
                              default=ADVISOR_REQUEST_STATUS_ACCEPTED)
    # Data field holds calculated indexed data which is for UI consumption and doesn't change over time.
    data = JSONField(default=dict, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['advisor', 'status'],
                name='unique_advisor_accepted_response',
                condition=models.Q(status=ADVISOR_REQUEST_STATUS_ACCEPTED)
            )
        ]
```

However, there are already existing database that has duplicate Status accepted for one response and that is causing Integrity Error:

```
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: could not create unique index "unique_advisor_accepted_response"        
DETAIL:  Key (advisor_id, status)=(11, accepted) is duplicated
```

I don't want to delete data in prod, how should I approach this migration so constraint on previous data is not applied like skipped over and only on new data being inserted.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a new field on your model for seperate new and old data. First remove your unique constraint on your model.

```py
is_new = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

You should add a function to your migration file for set is_new False for old records.

```py
def forwards_func(apps, schema_editor):
    AdvisorResponse= apps.get_model("myapp", "AdvisorResponse")
    AdvisorResponse.objects.all.update(is_new=False)

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = []

    operations = [
        # Your is_new field operation should be here.
        migrations.RunPython(forwards_func),
    ]
```

Now you can add your unique constraint like this. Your unique constraint works only new records.

```py
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['advisor', 'status'],
                name='unique_advisor_accepted_response',
                condition=models.Q(status=ADVISOR_REQUEST_STATUS_ACCEPTED, is_new=True)
            )
        ]
```